# how to highlight active nav menu when scrolled in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, menu, highlight

how will I show all the nav menus if they don't have any space to show?

I want to make my navbar like site have https://restoranserisentosapj.weeat.asia/cust/#/goods
what I make is https://srbistro.netlify.app/ (please check in the phone or phone view)